# Javascript add Content on HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello guys i have an javascript code and i need to add it on html the problem is idk how to do that since i dont have an ID as a reference.

```
for (m = 0; m < novaLista.length; m++) {
    if (novaLista[m].upMenu == 0) {
        console.log(novaLista[m]);
        $("#treeview-menu").append('<li class="treeview"><a href="#"><i class="' +
            novaLista[m].icon + '"></i><span>' +
            novaLista[m].name + '</span><i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a></li>');
        for (l = 0; l < novoMenu.length; l++) {
            if (novaLista[m].id == novoMenu[l].upMenu) {
                console.log(novoMenu[l]);
                //I DONT KNOW HOW TO ADD THIS SUBMENU SINCE THE REFERENCE IS ON TOPMENU HERE ON THE LOOP ABOVE
                $().append('<ul class="treeview-menu"><li><a href="relatorio-prestacao-conta.html><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Relatorio  de Prestacao de Contas</a></li></ul>');
            }
        }

        //</li>
    }
}
```

this is the HTML

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu" id="treeview-menu">
                    <li class="header" id="menu"></li>
                    <li id="submenu"></li>>
                        <!-- 
                        <li class="treeview">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
                                <span>Financeiro</span>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                            </a>

                            <ul class="treeview-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="relatorio-prestacao-conta.html">
                                        <i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> 
                                        Relatório de Prestação de Contas
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        --> 
                </ul>
```

i comented the submenu and the topmenu here in the HTML

Comment: More important than the script would be the html, so we can help you with what selectors to pick.

Comment: what is `TOPMENU`? is `#treeview-menu` the right selector? how is it different from `.treeview-menu`? what's the HTML look like?

Comment: What's in `novaLista` & `novaMenu`?

Comment: @JKirchartz they have objects that come from a json. its like a dynamic menu for a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to target the most recently added `li.treeview` with

```
$('.treeview').last().append(...);
```

(where `...` is your original html/code)

Answer (score 0):

Just store the element in a variable:

```
var submenu = $("#treeview-menu").append('<li class="treeview"><a href="#"><i class="' +
            novaLista[m].icon + '"></i><span>' +
            novaLista[m].name + '</span><i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a></li>');
```

Then you can append to it:

```
submenu.append('<ul class="treeview-menu"><li><a href="relatorio-prestacao-conta.html><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Relatorio  de Prestacao de Contas</a></li></ul>');
```